# Cannot start any emulator anymore

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-studio-3.0

I tried to start AVDs, but I always get following error:

> Emulator: Process finished with exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)

I tried creating new AVDs and tried to switch usage of "Emulator performance" between "automatic, "hardware" and "software", but nothing helps, I always get the result from above.

The error comes instantly when I try to start an AVD.

Any ideas what could cause this? I *think* this issue came with the update to android studio 3.0...

**Edit - Environment:**

- Windows 10 (high end business notebook, dell precisison 7510)
- Android Studio 3.0
- SDK Tools:

  - Android Emulator 26.1.4: installed
  - Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator (HAXM installer): installed

**What I tried**

- deleted the complete Android SDK (SDK only, without android studio) and installed it again (without success).
- tried using an emulator with auto/hardware/software graphics setting => same exception in every case
- updated intel and nvidia driver (it may be related to this, as there exist driver problems with my notebook), but did not help either
- deleted virtual device and created a new one => did not help either

**Additional informations**

Tried to start the emulator with "emulator @Name_of_AVD -verbose" from the command line, this gives me following informations (manually translated, so may not be 100% accurate):

1. Popup window with following:

   **Title**: qemu-system-i386.exe - Entry point not found

   **Text**: The procedure entry point "_Z4endlR11QTextStream" was not found in DLL "M:\AndroidSDK\emulator\lib64\qt\lib\Qt5Svg.dll".
2. Popup window with following:

   **Title**: qemu-system-i386.exe - Entry point not found

   **Text**: The procedure entry point "_Z11qt_assert_xPKcS0_S0_i" was not found in DLL "M:\AndroidSDK\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-i386.exe".
3. Complete console output:

   ```
   emulator:Android emulator version 27.0.2.0 (build_id 4498654) (CL:f388734068bae38c6115263feea33c68eed531fe)
   emulator:Found AVD name 'Nexus_5_API_25'
   emulator:Found AVD target architecture: x86
   emulator:argv[0]: 'emulator.exe'; program directory: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator'
   emulator:  Found directory: M:\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\

   emulator:Probing for M:\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\/kernel-ranchu: file exists
   emulator:Auto-config: -engine qemu2 (based on configuration)
   emulator:  Found directory: M:\AndroidSDK/system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\

   emulator:emuDirName: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator'
   emulator:try dir M:\AndroidSDK\emulator
   emulator:Trying emulator path 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe'
   emulator:Found target-specific 64-bit emulator binary: M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe
   emulator:Adding library search path: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/lib64'
   emulator:Adding library search path: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/lib64/gles_swiftshader'
   emulator:Adding library search path: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/lib64/gles_angle'
   emulator:Adding library search path: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/lib64/gles_angle9'
   emulator:Adding library search path: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/lib64/gles_angle11'
   emulator: Adding library search path for Qt: 'M:\AndroidSDK\emulator\lib64\qt\lib'
   emulator: Setting Qt plugin search path: QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=M:\AndroidSDK\emulator\lib64\qt\plugins
   emulator:Quoted param: [M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe]
   emulator:Quoted param: [@Nexus_5_API_25]
   emulator:Quoted param: [-verbose]
   emulator: Running :M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe
   emulator: qemu backend: argv[00] = "M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe"
   emulator: qemu backend: argv[01] = "@Nexus_5_API_25"
   emulator: qemu backend: argv[02] = "-verbose"
   emulator: Concatenated backend parameters:
   M:\AndroidSDK\emulator/qemu/windows-x86_64/qemu-system-i386.exe @Nexus_5_API_25 -verbose
   ```
4. Emulator settings:

   ```
   AvdId=Nexus_5_API_25
   PlayStore.enabled=true
   abi.type=x86
   avd.ini.displayname=Nexus 5 API 25
   avd.ini.encoding=UTF-8
   disk.dataPartition.size=800M
   fastboot.forceColdBoot=no
   hw.accelerometer=yes
   hw.audioInput=yes
   hw.battery=yes
   hw.camera.back=emulated
   hw.camera.front=emulated
   hw.cpu.arch=x86
   hw.cpu.ncore=1
   hw.dPad=no
   hw.device.hash2=MD5:1c925b9117dd9f33c5128dac289a0d68
   hw.device.manufacturer=Google
   hw.device.name=Nexus 5
   hw.gps=yes
   hw.gpu.enabled=yes
   hw.gpu.mode=auto
   hw.initialOrientation=Portrait
   hw.keyboard=yes
   hw.lcd.density=480
   hw.lcd.height=1920
   hw.lcd.width=1080
   hw.mainKeys=no
   hw.ramSize=1536
   hw.sdCard=yes
   hw.sensors.orientation=yes
   hw.sensors.proximity=yes
   hw.trackBall=no
   image.sysdir.1=system-images\android-25\google_apis_playstore\x86\
   runtime.network.latency=none
   runtime.network.speed=full
   sdcard.size=100M
   showDeviceFrame=yes
   skin.dynamic=yes
   skin.name=nexus_5
   skin.path=M:\AndroidSDK\skins\nexus_5
   tag.display=Google Play
   tag.id=google_apis_playstore
   vm.heapSize=128
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You've to check:

- Your **size on disk** is not full - this's often happen due to creation of some virtual devices that are unused in AVD Manager (So delete unused if any)
- The RAM size of Emulator should not minimum as your requirements

In work around steps (tested) :

1. Restart your Android Studio
2. Create new device in your AVD Manager
3. Increase the RAM size of the Emulator

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding. It will be bst to use Genymotion as compared to AVD. Link is [HERE](https://www.genymotion.com/fun-zone/)

1. Download Genymotion.
2. Download Virtual Box if its not with Genymotion.
3. Choose Any type device for testing in Android.

**NOTE : At Least 4 GB RAM is required to use Both Android Studio and Genymotion.**

By Applying some zip files you can also use Genymotion to test  for Google Map testing and also you will be able to use Google Play Services

Answer (score 0):

Just thinking of new features Multi-dex or Instant App Settings are messing up with your project. One last try:
Disable Instant Run
To disable Instant Run:

> Open the Settings or Preferences dialog. Navigate to Build, Execution,
>   Deployment > Instant Run. Uncheck the box next to Enable Instant Run.

Ignore if you feel this is inappropriate.

Comment: I'm not using instant run, feels like it costs more than I get from it (every now and then I saw bugs and then I was looking for the solution in my code whereas I only needed to recompile my project instead because IR messed something up)

Answer (score 0):

Creating new AVD.

also

Get Android Studio 3.1 if 3.0 is still giving the issue, 3.1 has new DEX compiler D8 where as 3.0 has DX.

as CodeBulls said above instant run may also be an issue

Answer (score 0):

The `exit code -1073741511 (0xC0000139)` Stands for Some Error with C or C++ Dependency File. That is Some DLL Files ae Missing For The Emulator.

So Update **Android Emulator** From **SDK Tools**

Update and Instal **Google play Intel Atom x86 System Image**  for the SDK Platform which is Using to Run The Emulator (**API 25**).

Hope This Will Help You to Resolve Your Problem

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check below things into your notebook.

This happens when you upgrade your windows and hyper-v virtual machine's configurations are not updated alongside.

Open Hyper-V Manager app (in windows 10) > choose your machine that's giving erros > on the right, click 'upgrade configuration' and choose 'upgrade'.

That should update your Virtual Machine configuration for that windows 10 phone emulator and the emulator should work fine.

This problem occurred on both of my laptops and doing this fixed it.

if your problem is still not solved then please follow below link it helps you.

http://www.itwriting.com/blog/9371-how-to-run-android-studio-on-windows-without-disabling-hyper-v.html

hope this helps you try it.